# Executing all suites from Ant

Tags: java, ant, fitnesse

I have few test suites(say 5) defined in **fitNesse** which are working independently when I execute each of them by going manually to the browser and then hit the Suite button on each Suite. But I wanted all of them to be executed sequential wise automatically like Suite1, Suite2 and so on. So, I have searched and tried a lot and finally figured out that I can run a suite from command line, so I kept in Ant build file as following.

```
  <java fork="true" classname="MainClass" classpathref="testing.classpath" jvm="${java.home}/bin/java">
  <jvmarg value="-Dresorce.Path=${baseDir}/res" />
    <arg line="-p 8000"/>
    <arg line="-d ."/>
    <arg line="-e 0"/>
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg value="fitnesse.TestSuites.Suite1?suite&amp;format=text"/>
  </java>
```

In the above way I am able to execute `suite1` from command prompt. What I want is to execute all the suites one after the other. I also want to separate starting the `fitnesse` and all prerequisites in one target and then executing suites in the other target which depends on target1 like below

```
<target name="buildrun" >

      <java fork="true" classname="MainClass" classpathref="testing.classpath" jvm="${java.home}/bin/java">
      <jvmarg value="-Dresorce.Path=${baseDir}/res" />
        <arg line="-p 8000"/>
        <arg line="-d ."/>
        <arg line="-e 0"/>
      </java>
</target>
<target name="suitesrun" depends="buildrun">

     //Here suites should be specified to run on the above port
</target>
```

So, can someone please guide me how to go further with suitesrun in such a way that it runs all the suites on the port that **Fitnesse** is running on?